# помогите разобраться с многопоточкой

Tags: java, многопоточность

Ковыряю многопоточку, пробую заполнить лист числами параллельно, а потом вывести в консоль.
И насколько я понимаю, jvm запускает поток в зависимости от фазы луны, а метод join останавливает другие потоки, пока  метод не доработает.
И вызывая join у двух потоков у нас получается последовательное выполнение а не параллельное.??
как заполнить параллельно лист и вывести его в конце в консоль?

```
public class Solution {
    static List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                list1.add(i);
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--) {
                list2.add(i);
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
//        thread1.join();

        thread2.start();
//        thread2.join();

        printList(list1);
        printList(list2);
    }

    static void printList(List<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.print(integer);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: `start, start, join, join` - будет параллельное исполнение.

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы посторонний поток как-то просигнализировал основному потоку, что он выполнил работу. это называется Реактивное Программирование. можно, конечно, и без него заморочить и изобрести квадратное колесо, но лучше сразу гуглите в сторону RxJava.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy так join вроде блокирует исполнение других потоков?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что `join останавливает другие потоки`? Это не так. join останавливает поток, который вызывает join, пока другой поток (`join` метод которого вызвали) не закончит свое выполнение.

Comment: `join` блокирует исполнение только вызывающего потока. Пока он висит на первом `join` обе нитки делают свое дело.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy  при вызове  `join` на потоке, этот поток отработает первым? или он отработает когда другие потоки завершаться?

Comment: Оба потока начнут работать с момента вызова соответствующего `start`. И буду работать параллельно. Основной поток-бездельник почти сразу повиснет на первом `join`, дождётся завершения первого потока, зависнет на втором `join` (если второй поток подотстал) и завершится.

Comment: То как вы вызываете `join` вообще не влият на исполнение других тредов. Это просто способ подписаться на событие завершение другой нити.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy я вас понял, благодарю, я просто думал что join блокирует другие потоки пока текущий не завершиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать:

```
public class Solution {
    static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                synchronized(list) {
                    list.add(i);
                }
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--) {
                synchronized(list) {
                    list.add(i);
                }
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
        thread1.join();

        printList(list);
    }

    static void printList(List<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Обратите внимание на синхронизацию доступа к списку.

Comment: добавьте в каждый метод задержку в 1000мс и посмотрите что будет.

Comment: Говорите прямо, что хотите сказать.